# Finding out connected components of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have found this problem in my textbook.

[image]

It is a disconnected graph , but it was also written there that it has 3 components. But i couldn't separate those components.

Can anyone please explain clearly

i) What does connected component really mean?

ii) What are the 3 components of the graph?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to label the vertices. I labeled them with letters $A,B,C,\dots$ starting with the vertex at the top and proceeding clockwise. Note that the vertices $B,C$ are joined by edges only to $I,J,K,$ and the vertices $I,J,K$ are joined only to $B,C.$ This tells us that the subgraph $H$ induced by the vertices $B,C,I,J,K$ is a connected component (isomorphic to the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,3}$); namely, **each vertex of $H$ is joined by a path (of length one or two) to every other vertex of $H,$ and there are no edges joining any vertex in $H$ to any vertex not in $H.$** That's what it means to be a connected component.

Now you can find the other two components.

Comment: is it A,B,I,J,K or B,C,I,J,K?

Comment: @IAmBlake Thanks for the correction.